# Scanner with ADF that will save to USB memory stick

Tags: usb, pdf, scanner, jpeg, peripherals

Is there such a thing as a scanner with an automatic document feeder and a duplexer, that will scan to a USB memory stick?

Other requirements, must be able to save as PDF (inc multipage PDF) or JPG.

Network connectivity would be nice, direct PC connection not required.

Comment: Man, I wish this question wasn't closed.. This problem has been plaguing me for a while.

Comment: What exchange *can* this question be asked on?

Comment: @wberry I believe shopping questions are off topic on all the SE sites now, but FWIW I never did find an exact match for my requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> USB means the ultimate in simplicity
>   and versatility. Print quickly -
>   without using a PC - by connecting any
>   PictBridge™ camera or phone directly
>   to the printer. You can also connect
>   USB memory to the printer and print
>   instantly. **Even when you don’t have
>   access to a PC, you can save what you
>   scanned directly to a USB memory.**

Quote from Samsung re their CLX3175-FN

Comment: no duplex though.

Comment: I should have also stated that I didn't really want the overhead of a MFP, as the printing functionality will never be used, however it's looking like a dedicated scanner that does what I want simply doesn't exist.

I'll probably just install a dedicated scanning station - i.e. scanner with  an ADF, connected via USB to a networked PC with a custom replacement shell that allows users to scan direct to their home directory.

Comment: Accepted as the best match to my spec.

Answer (score 1):

The Kodak ScanStation 100 will do what you want. You can scan directly to a USB drive without having the scanner attached to a pc. The ScanStation is a standalone networked device that has an embedded version of XP running on the device. You can scan to FTP, email, a network share or a USB drive directly attached to the scanner. It will save files as pdf, jpg or tiff. We have used this device for approximately 3 years. It is about $2500 USD for the basic device.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no such scanner

Answer (score 0):

Unless i'm misreading your requirements, the [**Fujitsu ScanSnap S1500**](http://www.fujitsu.com/us/services/computing/peripherals/scanners/scansnap/scansnap-s1500.html) or one of it's brethren might work. I have the S1500 and it does full color duplex scanning with ADF to wherever you want, with optional PDF, OCR, etc. It is small (about the size of a bread box), very fast, currently about $420 street price for [**just the scanner**](http://amzn.com/B001V9LQH0) or $440 for the [**Deluxe Bundle**](http://amzn.com/B0021AERWY). The Deluxe Bundle comes with Acrobat 9 Standard, CardMinder business card software, and Rack2-Filer V5.0, so it's well-worth the extra $20.

[image: ScanSnap S1500 Closed] [image: ScanSnap S1500 Open]

Comment: the Fujitsu requires a windows pc, and cannot scan to a usb memory stick without pc.